# I want to build a simple calculator

Tags: java, android, xml, calculator

Did I forget something essential? B/c Android Studio doesn't give any error's but when running the application and pressing the button(CALCULATE), the app instantly crashes.

Error is as following:

> "Unfortunately, Calc has stopped."

Java code(callation.java):

```
package com.iodine.calc;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class callation extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_callation);

    EditText am = new EditText(this);
    EditText pm = new EditText(this);
    Button b = new Button(this);

    am = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number1);
    pm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number2);
    final TextView om = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    final String am1 = am.getText().toString();
    final String pm1 = pm.getText().toString();
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View b){
            om.setText(am1);
            final Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(am1);
            final Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(pm1);

            switch (b.getId()) {
                case R.id.plus:
                 Double totalD = number1 + number2;
                 String totalS = Double.toString(totalD);
                 om.setText("The answer is: " + totalS);
                    break;
                case R.id.minus:
                    Double totalD1 = number1 - number2;
                    String totalS1 = Double.toString(totalD1);
                    om.setText("The answer is: " + totalS1);
                    break;
                case R.id.multiply:
                    Double totalD2 = number1 * number2;
                    String totalS2 = Double.toString(totalD2);
                    om.setText("The answer is: " + totalS2);
                    break;
                case R.id.divide:
                    Double totalD3 = number1 / number2;
                    String totalS3 = Double.toString(totalD3);
                    om.setText("The answer is: " + totalS3);
                    break;

        }





        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_callation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

XML code(activity_callation.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".callation">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/number2"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/number1"
    android:inputType="number" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/plus"
    android:id="@+id/plus"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/minus"
    android:id="@+id/minus"
    android:layout_above="@+id/multiply"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/multiply"
    android:id="@+id/multiply"
    android:layout_below="@+id/plus"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/divide"
    android:id="@+id/divide"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/multiply"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/minus"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/minus" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:textColorHighlight="#010101"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/calc"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/minus"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Could you please check my Java and/or XML code? I'd appreciate it if you could correct me on my mistakes and find a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should post the error you're getting in the crash

Comment: It's an android OS error like: "Unfortunately, Calc has stopped." This happens as soon as I click on the button.

(Calc is the name of my app)
Like I said: Android Studio doesn't give any errors while running the code.

Comment: You should get the error from the LOGCAT, not from the message the user usually gets.

Answer (score 1):

First place this will crash:

```
final Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(am1);
```

You cannot parse a null value. Since you never refresh am1 or pm1 (which you cant anyways since you set them to final) they are null as they are only set on init. That is where I would guess your crash is happening.

Other thoughts:

This will not work even if it doesn't crash as the listener is only on the equals button and you are trying to get which of the radio buttons is selected from the passed in view to the onclick. This will always be what threw the event (in this case the calc button). to solve this put the radio buttons in a radio group then get which one is selected from that.

You do not have to preset the edittext... before setting them:

```
EditText am = new EditText(this);
EditText pm = new EditText(this);
Button b = new Button(this);
```

to

```
final EditText am = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.number1);
...
```

am1 and pm1 don't need to be outside the listener put them inside this will also not make you have to set them to final (which you don't in the fist place but i get that that is why you set them to final)

There are other errors but this will get you started.

One other reaaaaalllllyyyy important thing you name your button and the onClick pass in parameter to the same thing (b) this is REALY! bad.

also the next time you ask a question like this add the LOGCAT. you can find it on the android tab at the bottom of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is very tricky:

```
final Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(am1);
final Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(pm1);
```

Allways remember that, if u parse you need to surround it with try/catch block.If the user writes something that cant be parsed into a double value (like a letter for example) this line of code, will throw and exception.

NumberFormatException - if string cannot be parsed as a double value.

This is what you can change to avoid that:

```
try {
        final Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(am1);
        final Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(pm1);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert only numeric values!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```

This way you will just make a toast,and you will avoid the exception.

Answer (score -1):

I think you accidentally forgot the:

```
android:onClick="whatever"
```

where your button is. Just place this function inside of your calc button XML. Inside of the double quotes put the function, or in your case, I would recommend creating a new method called calcFunc and putting your onClick in there, like this:

```
public void calcFunc(View view){
  EditText am = new EditText(this);
  EditText pm = new EditText(this);
  Button b = new Button(this);

  am = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number1);
  pm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number2);
  final TextView om = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
  final String am1 = am.getText().toString();
  final String pm1 = pm.getText().toString();
  b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View b){
        om.setText(am1);
        final Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(am1);
        final Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(pm1);

        switch (b.getId()) {
            case R.id.plus:
             Double totalD = number1 + number2;
             String totalS = Double.toString(totalD);
             om.setText("The answer is: " + totalS);
                break;
            case R.id.minus:
                Double totalD1 = number1 - number2;
                String totalS1 = Double.toString(totalD1);
                om.setText("The answer is: " + totalS1);
                break;
            case R.id.multiply:
                Double totalD2 = number1 * number2;
                String totalS2 = Double.toString(totalD2);
                om.setText("The answer is: " + totalS2);
                break;
            case R.id.divide:
                Double totalD3 = number1 / number2;
                String totalS3 = Double.toString(totalD3);
                om.setText("The answer is: " + totalS3);
                break;

    }
}
```

Then set the onClick like this:

```
 android:onClick="calcFunc"
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference since the `OnClickListener` is being set programmatically. Furthermore, your code won't work properly because the code that should be run is inside a listener that won't get called until the second time the button is pressed.